# Accessing spring property file from outside war file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

accessing property file from outside war file then am getting error message
its absolute path then working fine .Please help

```
<util:properties id="configs" location="${ext.prop.file}/config.properties" /> --Not working
```

ext.prop.file = "**c:/test**

```
<util:properties id="configs" location="file:/c:/test/config.properties" /> -- Working fine
```

Comment: can u try like:  <util:properties id="configs" location="file:/${ext.prop.file}/config.properties" />

Comment: no luck.this format also

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by simply adding it to the `context` of the application at the time of context loading.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${propfile}"/>
```

Above config will load the property file onto the context using the variable `propFile`. This variable is declared at runtime, as below.

```
-DpropFile="file:/path/to/file.properties"
```

Thereafter, you can use `@Values` annotation in your class to access properties from this file.

```
@Values("${someVal}")
private String someVal;
```

Above statement is trying to access property with key as `someVal` in property file and assign it to `String someVal`.